# Who's holding the honey jar?

Tags: definite-articles

The following is a excerpt from William Cowper's translation of Homer's *Iliad* (Homer being the Greek poet, not the cartoon character, in this case):

> So saying, he cast his sceptre on the ground
>   Studded with gold, and sat. On the other side
>   The son of Atreus all impassion'd stood,
>   When the harmonious orator arose
>   Nestor, the Pylian oracle, whose lips
>   Dropped eloquence—**the honey not so sweet**.

The way I see it (correct me if I'm wrong) the last two lines mean that each time Nestor made a speech, it was a masterpiece that touched everyone deeply: sweet, oh, so sweet. Sweeter, in fact, than honey.

So why not just say "honey"? Why does Cowper say "the honey" instead? The honey. Some concrete honey, a specific amount, probably in a jar - did someone bring a jar of honey to the conference? Who? Ajax? Achilles? To what end? And where is it now? Or have they already eaten it all?

Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Billy needs the article to make the line in [his version](http://www.naxos.com/mainsite/blurbs_reviews.asp?item_code=NA306212&catNum=NA306212&filetype=About%20this%20Recording&language=English) scan in iambic pentameter.

Comment: Really? That's the reason? Hmm.

Comment: Although *not backed up by references* (and anyway, I doubt that's possible here), that is probably the reason.

Comment: Also none of the other lines is in Iambic pentameter

Comment: @PhilMJones: Actually, they are.

Comment: The **son**
of  **A**
treus **all**
im **pass**
ion'd **stood**

Comment: Homie had the opposite problem.  He needed *μέλίτος* (of honey) without the article *τού* screwing up the dactylic hexameter.

Comment: What ghastly scansion! Every line, other than the 6th, requires a missed syllable to make it work. but I do concede that I appear to be wrong.

Comment: @PhilMJones A bit of light reading on the google reveals a consensus that Cowper's blank verse is clumsy and plodding, possibly because his translation is so faithful.  All I've read (except the above) is the prologue, but if the style is consistent, Cowper's critics are right.  The verse clunks along, especially in comparison to the original, which soars.